# Design - Selecting DOM elements - ID or CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

We have a Angular 1.x app. Each screen/layout has multiple widgets. We have new requirement to inject a help icon into every widget. To make the setup less intrusive, we have come up with a controller which looks up for the widgets and then injects the icon dynamically.

I would like to ask the UI experts here regarding the appraoch to be used to select the widgets (and hence inject the icon into them). Is selecting by a CSS selector better than selecting by ID (say widget ID)? What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Thanks,
Midhun

Comment: As far as I am aware, there's basically no 'best' approach; you use whatever selector is valid to select the target element. The only real thing to avoid is duplicate IDs, as that would make for invalid markup. Other than that, it doesn't matter, and your question boils down to personal opinion (making it off-topic for StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to create attribute level directive instead.

1. it can be parameterized like `help-article="create_category"` or even using several attributes
2. it's safer to keep classes and id for styling while linking logic to custom attributes
3. more expected in angular world